# how to hide code messages when knitting r markdown

Tags: r, markdown, knitr

I'm trying to knit my r file to html and have the tables/graphs/certain outputs showing, but not the code chunks.
So far I have been successful with using echo = FALSE or include = FALSE in the start of the code chunk, but in my assumptions graphs the code messages that pop up are being knitted when I don't want them to be.
echo=FALSE shows the graphs along with the messages (which i don't want)
include=FALSE gets rid of the messages, but also gets rid of the graphs that i need to show.
Is there any way around this? I have attached example pictures to demonstrate. Thanks!

[image: the code chunk and its messages]

[image: the knitted end result]

Comment: Did you try `results = 'asis'', message = FALSE`?

Comment: Thanks, this worked perfectly when combined with the other answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Near the top you should see the code

```
knitr::opts_chunk$set(checo = TRUE)
```

You can add warning = FALSE at the end:

```
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE, warning = FALSE)
```

At the very top where it says output: you can also do this

```
output:
   html_document:
     code_folding: hide
```

This gives the option to show the code if someone wants to see it, but will hide it initially.

Comment: Thanks, this worked perfectly when combined with the other answer :)